# preload css-background-images for jquery transition in sencha-touch

Tags: jquery, css, sencha-touch

in my sencha-touch appp I have a jquery animation of the backbround-images via CSS-transition. the problem is that the fades to the next images doesn't work unit every image has been fully loaded once. so the first round of the slideshow isn't smootly changig.

is there any way to preload the images used as css-background-images?
thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery you can use something like this to preload images:

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'image.png').load(function() {
//... do stuff.
});
```

Edit:
Here is the function reference: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: this preloads the images without 'doing stuff' (empty function)?

Comment: Yes, the function is simply the callback. Means, you can fire an event or something after the image was loaded. In your case you could set a flag or something to check if your background was loaded.

Comment: but istn't this code setting the source of every image-tag to that path?

Comment: or: isn't it neccessary to have at least one IMG tag in action?

Comment: ok. - the function should be corrected to:
`$('#preloadImageContainer').load('app/images/' + allBackgroundImages[i], function() {
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });`

Comment: With my example, a dummy img-tag is generated. Once the image is loaded inside this element, it is also available for all other parts of the website. So, it is not neccessary to have any images inside the action.